# Configure Omeka S to Use Keycloak

Tags: php, keycloak, config, openid-connect, omeka

I have Omeka S (CMS) running on Apache2 server and Keycloak runing on Keycloak-server. I want to configuret Omeka web app. with Keycloak.

Omeka is a free, open-source content management system for online digital collections. As a web application, it allows users to publish and exhibit cultural heritage objects, and extend its functionality with themes and plugins. Wikipedia
Initial release date: February 21, 2008
Programming language: PHP
Developer: Corporation for Digital Scholarship, Roy Rosenzweig Center for History and New Media
Operating system: LAMP
Repository: github.com/omeka/Omeka

I try that but it's mot working.
Configure Omeka S to Use Keycloak:

In your Omeka S application's configuration (config/local.config.php), configure the OIDC adapter using the Keycloak client settings you configured.

```
php
return [
    'authentication' => [
        'adapters' => [
            'oidc' => [
                'options' => [
                    'clientId'                => 'your-client-id',
                    'clientSecret'            => 'your-client-secret',
                    'issuer'                  => 'https://your-keycloak-server/auth/realms/your-realm',
                    'redirectUri'             => 'https://your-omeka-s-app/callback', // Replace with your callback URL
                    'authorization_endpoint'  => 'https://your-keycloak-server/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
                    'token_endpoint'          => 'https://your-keycloak-server/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
                    'userinfo_endpoint'       => 'https://your-keycloak-server/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```